# What ways are there to increase MECs' ammo efficiency?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I am early in my first playthrough of XCOM: Enemy Within, and it seems that one of the limiting / balancing factors in MEC performance is ammunition: The minigun seems to only carry ammo for two shots, and a single use of Collateral Damage exhausts it. What ways are there to improve the number of shots that a MEC can get between reloading?

For example,

- Does the Ammo Conservation foundry upgrade apply to MECs?
- Is there something in the MEC skill tree to help with this?
- Are future MEC weapons more ammunition-efficient than the Minigun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All MEC weapons have the same amount of available ammo, enough for 2 shots before a reload. Ammo Conservation provides 1 extra shot, and so does the Expanded Storage, which is a MEC trooper skill for the Captain rank, for a total of 4 regular shots or 2 uses of Collateral Damage before a reload.